# Mod Rewrite Help

Tags: php, regex, mod-rewrite

I have some basic knowledge of Mod Rewrite, but I can't figure this out!

I want

http://example.com/posts/[NAME]/~[ID]/#[PAGE]

and be able to get it like $_GET['name'], $_GET['id'], and $_GET['page']

NAME is a en escaped string, so it allow A-Za-z1-9 and the special characters ?_-! (and replaced with %20, etc. , any amount of characters.

ID is a-zA-Z1-9, any amount of characters.

PAGE is a number, any amount of characters.

Also, I'm trying now: [NAME]-[ID]/[PAGE]/ but I don't need to $_GET['name'] in this one.

Having trouble getting this to work, as so far, I only really know how to do mod rewrite with ONE variable.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[NAME]/~[ID]/#[PAGE]`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^posts/([^/]+)/\~([^/]+)/#(\d+)$ your_file.php?name=$1&id=$2&page=$3 [QSA,L]
```

`[NAME]-[ID]/[PAGE]` without `$_GET['name']`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^posts/[^\-]+\-([^/]+)/(\d+)$ your_file.php?id=$1&page=$2 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Okay, I have a little issue. I'm trying now: [NAME]-[ID]/[PAGE]/ but I don't need to $_GET['name'] anymore.

Comment: would that be like: ^posts/([^/]+)/\-([^/]+)/([\d]+)/$ item.php?name=$1&fight=$2&page=$3

Comment: Can I ask what the # does after the / and also what [QSA,L] does?

Comment: why do you escape a - twice? I understood the first one, but the second what seems like it has errors? Am I wrong though?

Comment: @tap touch click: The `#` is there because you had it in your first version. It has no special meaning. It just needs to be there to match. `[QSA,L]` constists of two parts: `L` means that rewriting is finished after applying this rule. `QSA` means that we are extending the query parameters instead of replacing them.

Comment: @tap touch click: What's wrong with the `-`? Isn't it working as expected?

Comment: hm, I'm going to do some testing. I was confused because [^\-]+\-([^/]+) looks like — because of the escaped hyphen twice.

Comment: The first expression means that it should match everything _except_ a hyphen. The hyphen afterwards requires an actual hyphen to be there.

Comment: also, I have multiple rewrites, so would I only put the [QSA,L] after the last one? Thanks

Comment: `QSA` could be used on multiple rules, but `L` stops rewriting after the relevant rule matched.

Comment: http://example.com/posts/mac-1/1/ is 404ing with RewriteRule ^posts/[^\-]+\-([^/]+)/([\d]+)$ item.php?id=$1&page=$2

Comment: Try to remove the backslashes in front of the hyphens. It is possible that they do not need to be escaped.

Comment: still no luck with removing the \'s

Comment: might it have to do with Forcing a trailing slash above the rewrites

Comment: That is probably it. Try adding a trailing slash before `$`.

Comment: I added [/]* to the end and it no longer 404's. However, all the style sheet references became invalid.

Comment: What is the URL to your stylesheets?

Comment: Should I just add another ../ before the path, or is there a more "valid" approach to fixing this issue.

Comment: hm, well thats out of the scope of this thread. Thanks for your help elusive.

Comment: oh, one more thing (I promise it's the last). If I want the page to be optional, how can I configure that in the rewrite?

Comment: Change the `+` of the last block to `*` and add an ? after the trailing slash